# "sys.getrefcount()" return value

Tags: python

Why does

```
sys.getrefcount()
```

return 3 for every large number or simple string?Does that mean that 3 objects reside somewhere in the Program?Also,why doesn't setting x=(very large number) increase that object's ref count?Do those 3 ref counts result from my call to getrefcount?
Thank you for clarifying this.

for instance:

```
>>> sys.getrefcount(4234234555)
3
>>> sys.getrefcount("testing")
3
>>> sys.getrefcount(11111111111111111)
3
>>> x=11111111111111111
>>> sys.getrefcount(11111111111111111)
3
```

Comment: Although x="testing" increases the ref count,x=(large number) doesn't.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Large integer objects are not reused by the interpretor, so you get two distinct objects:

```
>>> a = 11111
>>> b = 11111
>>> id(a)
40351656
>>> id(b)
40351704
```

`sys.getrefcount(11111)` always returns the same number because it measures the reference count of a fresh object.

For small integers, Python always reuses the same object:

```
>>> sys.getrefcount(1)
73
```

Usually you would get only one reference to a new object:

```
>>> sys.getrefcount(object())
1
```

But integers are allocated in a special pre-malloced area by Python for performance optimization, and I suspect the extra two references have something to do with this.

It's implemented in [longobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/longobject.c) in CPython. (Update: link to Python3.) I do not claim to understand what's really going on. I think there are several things at work that cache temporary references:

```
print sys.getrefcount('foo1111111111111' + 'bar1111111111111') #1
print sys.getrefcount(111111111111 + 2222222222222)            #2
print sys.getrefcount('foobar333333333333333333')              #3
```

Answer (score 6):

1. Small strings and integers are cached by Python to save on object construction cost.
2. The interactive Python interpreter holds a temporary reference to each literal that you enter. Compare `getrefcount('foobar')` with `getrefcount('foo' + 'bar')`. (In the latter case, the interpreter has references to `'foo'` and `'bar'`.)
3. From the [manual](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.getrefcount):

> The count returned is generally one higher than you might expect, because it includes the (temporary) reference as an argument to `getrefcount()`.

Comment: So it's 1 for the cache+1 for the temporary ref.What about the third one?Does it belong to Python's internals?

Comment: @kaiseroskilo: no, it's +2 for temporary references; one in the interactive toplevel, and one in `getrefcount` itself because the object is passed as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that when you pass a direct number as an argument to sys.getrefcount, you have 3 references:

- 1 for the object itself (logical);
- 1 (temporary) for the object passed as argument to sys.getrefcount;
- and I would suppose 1 (temporary) for the interpreter, which I suppose converts the raw number (or string, or anything else) into an interpretable object.

For instance, let's consider this:

```
>>> sys.getrefcount(123456)
3

>>> a = 123456
>>> sys.getrefcount(a)
2
```

I don't really know what happens in the mind of Python, but it is interesting nonetheless. I can only guess the raw integer (ref #1) is temporarily converted into an int object (ref #2), which is then passed as an argument to sys.getrefcount (ref #3).

Comment: "which I suppose converts the raw number (or string, or anything else) into an interpretable object." There is no such thing as a "raw number". That is an integer or string literal, an aspect of source code, which creates a `int` or `str` object. There are *multiple references to that `int` object*.