# Unexpected value from sys.getrefcount

Tags: python, python-internals

Under Python 2.7.5

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getrefcount(10000)
3
```

Where are the three refcount?

PS: when the 10000 PyIntObject would be Py_DECREF to 0 ref and deallocated?
    Do not say about gc stuff, reference count itself can work without gc.

Comment: [**This previously asked question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302133/why-does-sys-getrefcount-return-2) might solve your problem... Apparently `sys.getrefcount()` always returns one more than the expected value.

Comment: That would be 2, I got 3

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["sys.getrefcount()" return value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544395/sys-getrefcount-return-value)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. When you do something in the REPL console, the string will be compiled internally and during the compilation process, Python creates an intermediate list with the list of strings apart from tokens. So, that is reference number 1. You can check this like this

   ```
   import gc
   print gc.get_referrers(10000)
   # [['sys', 'dis', 'gc', 'gc', 'get_referrers', 10000], (-1, None, 10000)]
   ```
2. Since its just a numeral, during the compilation process, peep-hole optimizer of Python, stores the number as one of the constants in the generated byte-code. You can check this like this

   ```
   print compile("sys.getrefcount(10000)", "<string>", "eval").co_consts
   # (10000,)
   ```

**Note:**

The intermediate step where Python stores 10000 in the list is only for the string which is compiled. That is not generated for the already compiled code.

```
print eval("sys.getrefcount(10000)")
# 3
print eval(compile("sys.getrefcount(10000)", "<string>", "eval"))
# 2
```

In the second example, we compile the code with the `compile` function and pass only the code object to the `eval` function. Now there are only two references. One is from the constant created by the peephole optimizer, the other is the one in `sys.getrefcount`.

Comment: But, why do I get the same thing when I put this in a file and run `python test.py`?  Wouldn't that take me out of the REPL?

Comment: You mean why you are getting 3?

Comment: Yes, that's the question of the night :)

Comment: @mgilson That is because, it still has to [parse](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Python/pythonrun.c#l1348) and [compile](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Python/pythonrun.c#l1367) the file

Comment: @mgilson You might want to see this [ASCII Cinema](https://asciinema.org/a/8320) as well. Here, I straight away execute the file and I get 3. I compile it and execute the bytecode, I get 2.

Comment: Ahh yes.  I believe you now -- Or maybe just that I _understand_ it now ... :).  Brilliant.  I love these questions because every time I end up digging a little deeper into the source code -- Generally it doesn't help, but at least I get a little more familiar with the code (and learn something when someone smarter than I figures out the actual answer)

Comment: @thefourtheye  One more question, as I asked, when exactly would the refcount down to 0, or when the code object would not hold 10000 anymore, inside Python source code, which part handle it?

Comment: @fsp The reference count for the constants in byte code, will not drop to 0 till the execution of the program is completed. Normally, [`Py_INCREF`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Include/object.h#l765) and [`Py_DECREF`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Include/object.h#l769) will increment and decrement the reference counts.