# Understanding sys.getrefcount differences in result

Tags: python, reference, sys

After reading about `sys.getrefcount`, I tried to play with it with the code below:

```
import sys
go = 102133333333333333333333333
sys.getrefcount(go)
>>> 2
sys.getrefcount(102133333333333333333333333)
>>> 3
```

Why am I getting this result, in particular the result of 3 references to the `102133333333333333333333333` number (or any high number, for that matter), and why it's higher than the reference count returned from the `go` variable?

Comment: The count returned is generally one higher than you might expect, because it includes the (temporary) reference as an argument to getrefcount().

Answer (score 3):

The `getrefcount` function returns the number of references, including:

1. The reference created for the argument;
2. All the references defined in the imported code.

Therefore, `1` which is pretty common, and most likely used a lot in the built-in modules, gives a lot of references:

```
>>> getrefcount(1)
136
```

The same applies for other immutable objects, such as strings and constants:

```
>>> getrefcount(True)
145
>>> getrefcount("a")
5
```

On my system, `102133333333333333333333333` gives `3` as well, which means that it is used twice in the code that was imported at the opening of the interpreter.

---

So why do you get these results?

Regarding the `go` variable, it has two references: one created when you define it, and another one when you pass it to `getrefcount`.

Now about `102133333333333333333333333`, or any large number.
First off, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22549723/7051394) explains why large numbers lead to `3` references.
Basically, small numbers are used in compiled code, and all the places where they are used point towards the same address.
On the other hand, when creating a number at runtime that doesn't exist in the compiled code, it is compiled and stored for optimization, which gives two references, plus the one passed to `getrefcount`.

But when a runtime number is assigned to two variables, the latter will **not** point towards the same address.
Therefore, the number of references will not increase, and stay at `3`.

Here is the demonstration:

```
>>> getrefcount(45)
9
>>> a = 45
>>> b = 45
>>> a is b
True
```

Now with a larger number:

```
>>> getrefcount(1000)
3
>>> a = 1000
>>> b = 1000
>>> a is b
False
```

The following shows how variables will not point towards the number address:

```
>>> a = 1000
>>> a is 1000
False
```