# Why does sys.getrefcount() give different value in console?

Tags: python, object, reference, sys

I tried to run `sys.getrefcount` for `int`(11) as below.

```
>>> a = 11
>>> b = 11
>>> id(a)
1845083728496
>>> id(b)
1845083728496
>>> id(11)
1845083728496
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getrefcount(a)
17
>>> sys.getrefcount(b)
17
>>> sys.getrefcount(11)
20
```

Why am i getting the result of **20** references to the number `11` and why it is higher than the reference count returned from `a` and `b` variables?.

But when i run the same as a standalone script, i am getting the same reference count for `a`, `b` and `11`, as below.

```
import sys

a = 11
b = 11

print("a : {}".format(a))
print("b : {}".format(b))
print('-----------------')

print("hex of a: {}".format(hex(id(a))))
print("hex of a: {}".format(hex(id(b))))
print("hex of 11: {}".format(hex(id(11))))
print('-----------------')

print("ref count of a: {}".format(sys.getrefcount(a)))
print("ref count of b: {}".format(sys.getrefcount(b)))
print("ref count of 11: {}".format(sys.getrefcount(11)))
```

Output:

```
a : 11
b : 11
-----------------
hex of a: 0x2dfac546a70
hex of a: 0x2dfac546a70
hex of 11: 0x2dfac546a70
-----------------
ref count of a: 28
ref count of b: 28
ref count of 11: 28
```

Answer (score 0):

Your concern is right. So It can't happen because sys.getrefcount() function tells you the reference count of an object.

I tried to run sys.getrefcount for int(11) as below.

```
>>> a = 11
>>> b = 11
>>> id(a)
1845083728496
>>> id(b)
1845083728496
>>> id(11)
1845083728496
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getrefcount(a)
17
>>> sys.getrefcount(b)
17
>>> sys.getrefcount(11)
20
```

So according to this code, you should get one answer. So I try this code from my pyharm IDE but that time its working correctly.

```
a = 11
b = 11

print(id(a))
#2452752788080
print(id(b))
#2452752788080
print(id(11))
#2452752788080
import sys
print(sys.getrefcount(a))
#30
print(sys.getrefcount(b))
#30
print(sys.getrefcount(11))
#30
```

And your 2nd code also working correctly. I supposed you using jupitor notebook or something kind of ide to write your 1st code. So I supposed that ide's Interactive prompts can have a lot going on behind the scenes. So I supposed that is the reason you didn't get the correct answer.

Comment: I have used shell (windows cmd) to run 1st code. I have tried again and it gives the same result.

Comment: Try normal IDE like pycharm,vs coding then you can realize the difference.

Comment: I am using atom and it looks fine if i run in it. But if i run the same in the Python shell [v3.9.6] i am getting this difference. Can you please try running the same in the shell at your end. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22550758/16915611 refer this one you can solve your problem.