# python why does getrefcount() always return 3 on some parameters

Tags: python, reference-counting

```
from sys import getrefcount
getrefcount("sgawgawrgrag") #3
getrefcount("ewtwgwqfgfdgd") #3
getrefcount(8658263842365) #3
... #3 3 3...
```

given some meaningless string or random large number, getrefcount() 'always' return 3.

why?

Comment: python 3.4: it returns 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["sys.getrefcount()" return value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544395/sys-getrefcount-return-value)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does sys.getrefcount() return 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302133/why-does-sys-getrefcount-return-2)